# Enviar mais de uma string para serial

Tags: c#, wpf

Estou criando um `string` através de dois valores, um deles lido através de um slider e outro de um check box. Junto os dois em uma string chamada `a` e envio ao mesmo tempo na serial.

Segue o código :

```
private async void SendSerial()
        {

             DirectionRotation = (bool)RotateInverter.IsChecked ? 1 : 0;// if ternario, check box marcado envia 1, check box desmarcado envia 0
            string a = _dataSent1 = $"{Pwm_Control.Value.ToString()},{DirectionRotation}";//cria string de envia para a serial
            if (sp.IsOpen)
            {
                sp.Write(a);//escreve na serial
            }
            else
            {

                await this.ShowMessageAsync("AVISO", "Porta desconectada");
            }

            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { StatusSerialSent.Text = $"StatusSerialSent : {a}"; });// mostra na tela valor que esta sendo enviado

        }
```

Gostaria de saber como poderia enviar duas strings, uma em sequencia da outra. Mas com um porém, por exemplo a string  com o valor do `check box` só é enviada quando o valor do mesmo é alterado. Alguém tem uma dica de como fazer?

Comment: Não entendi o que deseja provavelmente porque faltam informações, mas consigo ver problemas neste código, e acho que nenhum é relacionado com a pergunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terá que guardar o valor anterior para comparar com o atual, a variável PreviousDirectionRotation terá que ser definida dentro de um scope em que o valor não se "perca" entre pedidos à função SendSerial()

```
var PreviousDirectionRotation; // Variável para guardar o vaor anterior
            string a; // definir a var a fora do if
            DirectionRotation = (bool)RotateInverter.IsChecked ? 1 : 0;

            if (PreviousDirectionRotation != DirectionRotation)//Caso o valor anterior seja diferente do atual envia o valor atual e guarda o novo
            {

                a = _dataSent1 = $"{Pwm_Control.Value.ToString()},{DirectionRotation}";
                    PreviousDirectionRotation = DirectionRotation;
            }
            else // caso seja igual envia apenas o outro valor!
            {
                a = _dataSent1 = $"{Pwm_Control.Value.ToString()}";
            }
```